# php mail Failed To receive

Tags: php, email, ini

I am trying to use the PHP `mail()` function, However, it doesn't work and outputs the following error:

> "Warning: mail(): Failed to Receive in C:\wamp\www\site\indexmail.php
>   on line 29"

I think the issue caused by my IAP, because it works when I use another one.

Here's my `php.ini`:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = SSL0.OVH.net
smtp_server=SSL0.OVH.net
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = myadress@gmail.com


; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default:     "sendmail    -t -i").
;http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe"
```

I found the SSL0.OVH.net when i checked a mailbox of one of the employes. If anyone could help me please it would be great

Comment: PHP's `mail()` function has serious limitations. For virtually any use case where you'd consider it, you would be much much better off using Swift Mailer or PHPMailer instead.

Comment: It's not clear where you got "SSL0.OVH.net" from, not what makes you think it would the correct value to put into those two config values. It looks like a domain name; is it a domain owned by your employer? Is it their mail server? (if so, they probably wouldn't want you posting it here). Does it also require some kind of authentication credentials? All of this would be much easier to set up using PHPMailer, and you wouldn't have to mess around in the php.ini file either to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "*IAP*"?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use PHPMailer or Swift Mailer library. As I found in the docs the option smtp_server not exist.

Every online accessible SMTP-Server should ask for authentication because otherwise the mail server could be used for sending Spam. I didn't know a possibility to do that by php.ini

Also check your mail-configuration in a mail-client to be sure that they are not the problem.